# Como parar o comando end='' no Python

Tags: python, for

Estou com um problema que toda vez que uso o comando `end=''` ele não para!

**Exemplo:**

```
tabela = ('Palmeiras', 'Flamengo', 'Internacional')
for time in tabela:
    print(time, end=' ')
print('=-' * 20)
```

**Execução:**

```
Palmeiras Flamengo Internacional =-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-
```

Sendo que eu queria esse `=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-` na linha de baixo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Outro ponto importante é que você não precisa fazer um laça de repetição só para exibir os valores da tupla. Você pode gerar a *string* a partir do método `str.join`:

```
tabela = ('Palmeiras', 'Flamengo', 'Internacional')

print(' '.join(tabela))
print('=-' * 20)
```

Isso gera a saída:

```
Palmeiras Flamengo Internacional
=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-
```

Comment: Estranho, tinha tentado isso e `tabela.join(' ')` em um console online e tinha dado erro. Dai dei uma pesquisada e, pelo que entendi, tuplas não tem o método `join`, troquei os `()`  por `[]` dai funcionou

Comment: @GuilhermeCostamilam E não tem mesmo, o método `join` é da *string*, que recebe um iterável.

Answer (score 4):

O que acontece é que, quando você altera o valor de `end` na função, ele retira a quebra de linha automática, porque o valor padrão dele é `'\n'`

Então `print('foo')` assim como `print('foo', end='\n')` escreve "foo\n" e `print('foo', end=' ')` escreve "foo "

Se você quer adicionar essa quebra de linha basta fazer `print('\n', '=-' * 20)`, assim ele irá printar a quebra de linha e, depois, a string `=-` repetida 20 vezes

Answer (score 1):

Uma outra solução é preparar uma string e printar tudo de uma vez

```
tabela = ('Palmeiras', 'Flamengo', 'Internacional')
s = ''
for time in tabela:
    s += time + ' '
print(s[:-1]) # a parte `[:-1]` tira o ultimo espaço da string
print('=-' * 20)
```

Answer (score 1):

Para você resolver esta questão, uma das formas que sugiro é adicionar um `print vazio`,isto é, `"print()"` antes do seu último print.

O algoritmo ficaria desta forma...

```
tabela = ('Palmeiras', 'Flamengo', 'Internacional')
for time in tabela:
    print(time, end=' ')
print()
print(f'{"=-" * 20}\n')
```

Outra forma de resolver esta questão é:

```
tabela = ('Palmeiras', 'Flamengo', 'Internacional')
print(*tabela)
print('=-' * 20)
print()
```

Answer (score 1):

Amigo, consegui resolver usando a dica do Costamilam. Apenas atribuí o valor '\n' de volta ao end:

```
lista = ('Palmeiras', 'Flamengo', 'Internacional')
for time in lista:
  print(time, end=(" "))
print(end=('\n'))
print('=-' * 20)
```

Retorna:

```
Palmeiras Flamengo Internacional 
=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-
```